# Mutual exclusion among a group of services

Tags: systemd

I have a group of systemd services, let's call them `A.service`, `B.service`, `C.service` and `D.service`.

The execution of any of the services may interfere with any other of them, so I want them to be scheduled so that only one of these four services may run at any given time.

How can I do this is the best way?

#### Details and comments

- All services are long running `Type=oneshot`.
- The ordering of the services doesn't matter.
- I can modify the unit files for the services.
- Optimally the solution should work with an arbitrary number of services.
- Optimally the solution should work both if the services are run as timers, if they are started on boot, and if they are started manually. But a solution for only timers is also interesting.
- Optimally, if for example A is started (by a timer or manually) when B is already is running, then A should wait until B is finished, then A should start.
- Maybe I can solve the problem by declaring each of the services to be before or after the others. But I haven't figured out how to do that. It would probably also be pretty messy, and don't scale well to more services.
- Maybe the problem can be solved using "slices" and resource control in some way, but I haven't been able to figure out how.
- `TasksMax=1` does not seem to be right, because it counts threads, not services.
- I don't want a service to be stopped by another that wants to start, in the way that `Conflicts=` work.
- An optimal solution would be to have a hypothetical entry `MutualExclution=my-exclution-tag` in the unit files, which would make it so that only one unit with the same tag would be allowed to run at the same time. But I don't think there is such a unit file entry.

Comment: This looks like a job for `ConditionPath...` or `ConditonEnvironment`, and perhaps you may emulate the "waiting" behavior by dynamically setting `OnSuccess`/`OnFailure` of the waited-for service

Comment: @LL3: Yes, maybe conditionals can be used. But I have not been able to figure out how.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that systemd has a built-in facility to support the very specific semantics you've described, but it seems like you could trivially get what you want through the use of a lockfile. For each service, instead of running `/some/script/or/program`, wrap that in a call to `flock`:

```
ExecStart = /usr/bin/flock /tmp/my-exclusion-lock /some/script/or/program
```

If any of your services is running, any other service will block attempting to acquire the lock. When the running service exits, it will release the lock and one of the waiting services will start running.

Comment: flock, interesting! I think that would work! One disadvantage: systemd would report a service as running, even it is blocked in flock, waiting to start. I will evaluation this solution and get back to you.

Comment: It turns out your question was previously asked [in 2019](https://superuser.com/questions/1492025/systemd-how-to-make-two-services-mutually-exclusive-but-run-both), which includes a link to a [`systemd-devel` mailing list thread](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2019-October/043586.html) in which folks make the same suggestion I have made here.